# How to sort by position field

Tags: magento2, sorting, interface, repositories

This is my collection function:

```
public function getCollection()
{
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('status', '1')->create();

    $someCollection = $this->someRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria);

    return $someCollection->getItems();

}
```

So far everything works fine.

The filter works with no issues, all enabled items are displaying.

I need help with sorting. I have a field called "position". I need to display items in ascending way, what I mean is "position 1" should be first displayed item, second should be under first, etc.

As I suppose there should be an easy method for that but can't find it...

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to add sort order to search criteria

Add `\Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder` as dependency in constructor.

```
public function getCollection()
    {
        $sortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder->setField('position')->setDirection('DESC')->create();

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('status', '1')->setSortOrders([$sortOrder])->create();

        $someCollection = $this->someRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria);

        return $someCollection->getItems();

    }
```

Let me know in case you face any issue

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine!

Comment: How to search by custom product attribute(bestseller) using the above code. it's not working for custom product attributes. i have ask question for same. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/351047/how-to-use-custom-product-attribute-in-sorting-option-with-search-criteria-build