# How to use custom product attribute in sorting option with search criteria builder for magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, elasticsearch, search-criteria, sort-by-options

I have created one custom product attribute(bestseller). Now I want to sort by custom product attribute(bestseller) using search criteria builder sort by option but it's not working for custom product attribute. FYI Sort by option working with price attribute but not working with custom product attribute option. Any help appreciate...

```
//Code for fetch products based on search term.
$limit = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/frontend/list_per_page');    
$p = $p?$p:1;
$pageSize = $limit?$limit:20;            
$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeid);
$search_criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
$search_criteria->setRequestName("quick_search_container");
$search_criteria->setCurrentPage($p);
$search_criteria->setPageSize($pageSize);
$filter = $this->filterBuilder->setField('search_term')
->setValue($q)
->setConditionType("like")
->create();               
$filterGroup = $this->filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filter)->create();
$search_criteria->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup]);
$sortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder->setField('bestseller')->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_DESC)->create();
$search_criteria->setSortOrders([$sortOrder]);
$search_result = $this->searchInterface->search($search_criteria);
$totalSearchResults = $search_result->getTotalCount();        
$products = $search_result->getItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject 3 classes

```
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface;
```

check below code

```
   public function getList(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        /** @var \Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CustomModel\CollectionFactory $collection */
        $collection = $this->CustomModelListCollectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $filterGroup) {
            $fields = [];
            $conditions = [];
            foreach ($filterGroup->getFilters() as $filter) {
                if ($filter->getField() === 'store_id') {
                    $collection->addStoreFilter($filter->getValue(), false);
                    continue;
                }
                $fields[] = $filter->getField();
                $condition = $filter->getConditionType() ?: 'eq';
                $conditions[] = [$condition => $filter->getValue()];
            }
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($fields, $conditions);
        }

        $sortOrders = $searchCriteria->getSortOrders();
        if ($sortOrders) {
            /** @var SortOrder $sortOrder */
            foreach ($sortOrders as $sortOrder) {
                $collection->addOrder(
                    $sortOrder->getField(),
                    ($sortOrder->getDirection() === SortOrder::SORT_ASC) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'
                );
            }
        }
        $collection->setCurPage($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage());
        $collection->setPageSize($searchCriteria->getPageSize());
        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);

        /** @var \Custom\Module\Api\Data\CustomModelSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResults */
        $searchResults = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
        $searchResults->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
        $searchResults->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
        $searchResults->setItems($collection->getItems());

        return $searchResults;
    }
```

below sort condition

```
$sortOrders = $searchCriteria->getSortOrders();
        if ($sortOrders) {
            /** @var SortOrder $sortOrder */
            foreach ($sortOrders as $sortOrder) {
                $collection->addOrder(
                    $sortOrder->getField(),
                    ($sortOrder->getDirection() === SortOrder::SORT_ASC) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. can you share the dependency classes for this code?

Comment: Can you guide with my code where I need to change ?

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Any dependency for this line collectionProcessor ? $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);

Comment: yes Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface; this is the dependency